# HttpRequestException when call Api in xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, refit

In xamarin, I call the api using the refit library.
I have followed the [instructions](https://xamgirl.com/consuming-a-restful-web-service-in-xamarin-forms-using-refit-part-1/), but when calling the exception api was returned.
I don't know if my combination of prism will affect?
I have called a manual api but it also doesn't work
I also consulted on the internet but it seems everything still doesn't work.
In the Advanced Android Option I am setting the HttpClient implementation to Android, the SSL / TSL implementation is Default (Native TLS 1.2+)
. Can I help me?

```
public interface IMakeUpApi
{
    [Get("/api/v2/items")]
    Task<string> GetMakeups();
}
```

In MainPageViewModel

```
var apiResponse = RestService.For<IMakeUpApi>("https://qiita.com");
var makeups = await apiResponse.GetMakeups();
```

Error

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
>     Message=mono-io-layer-error (-1)
>     Source=mscorlib
>     StackTrace:
>     at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00180] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/ConnectHelper.cs:84 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ea] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:371 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) [0x000a2] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:529 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0003f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:284 
>     at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/RedirectHandler.cs:32 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x000b3] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:531 
>     at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2[T,TBody].b__0 (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, System.Threading.CancellationToken ct, System.Object[] paramList) [0x00188] in :0 
>     at TestApp.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel.Navigate () [0x0003b] in E:\H\Xamarin\TestApp\TestApp\TestApp\ViewModels\MainPageViewModel.cs:58 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__7_0 (System.Object state) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/AsyncMethodBuilder.cs:1021 
>     at Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0 () [0x00000] in :0 
>     at Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in :0 
>     at Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) [0x00009] in :0 
>     at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.39(intptr,intptr)

Detail Exception

> - ex  {System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: mono-io-layer-error (-1) ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: mono-io-layer-error (-1)
>     at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000c8] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/ConnectHelper.cs:65 
>     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>     at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00180] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/ConnectHelper.cs:84 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x000ea] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:371 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync (System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult] creationTask) [0x000a2] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:529 
>     at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[TResult].get_Result () [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Threading/Tasks/ValueTask.cs:813 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Boolean doRequestAuth, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0003f] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/HttpConnectionPool.cs:284 
>     at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync (System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00070] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/SocketsHttpHandler/RedirectHandler.cs:32 
>     at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] sendTask, System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts, System.Boolean disposeCts) [0x000b3] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:531 
>     at Refit.RequestBuilderImplementation+<>c__DisplayClass14_0`2[T,TBody].b__0 (System.Net.Http.HttpClient client, System.Threading.CancellationToken ct, System.Object[] paramList) [0x00188] in :0 
>     at TestApp.ViewModels.MainPageViewModel.Navigate () [0x00044] in E:\H\Xamarin\TestApp\TestApp\TestApp\ViewModels\MainPageViewModel.cs:60 }    System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
> - base    {System.Exception}  System.Exception
> - Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>         HResult -2147467259 int
>         HelpLink    (null)  string
> - InnerException  {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}    System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
> - base    {System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception}  System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
> - base    {System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException}  System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException
> - base    {System.SystemException}    System.SystemException
> - base    {System.Exception}  System.Exception
> - Data    {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>         HResult -2147467259 int
>         HelpLink    (null)  string
>         InnerException  (null)  System.Exception
>         Message "mono-io-layer-error (-1)"  string
>         Source  "mscorlib"  string
>         StackTrace  "  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threa…" string
> - TargetSite  {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo
> - base    {System.Reflection.MethodInfo}  System.Reflection.MethodInfo
>         Attributes  System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.FamANDAssem | System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.Family | System.Reflection.MethodAttributes.HideBySig   System.Reflection.MethodAttributes
>         CallingConvention   System.Reflection.CallingConventions.HasThis | System.Reflection.CallingConventions.Standard    System.Reflection.CallingConventions
>         ContainsGenericParameters   false   bool
> - DeclaringType   {System.RuntimeType}    System.RuntimeType
>         IsGenericMethod false   bool
>         IsGenericMethodDefinition   false   bool
>         IsSecurityCritical  true    bool
>         IsSecuritySafeCritical  true    bool
>         IsSecurityTransparent   false   bool
>         MetadataToken   100680451   int
> - MethodHandle    {System.RuntimeMethodHandle}    System.RuntimeMethodHandle
> - Module  {System.Reflection.RuntimeModule}   System.Reflection.RuntimeModule
>         Name    "Throw" string
> - ReflectedType   {System.RuntimeType}    System.RuntimeType
> - ReturnParameter {System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo}    System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo
> - ReturnType  {System.RuntimeType}    System.RuntimeType
> - ReturnTypeCustomAttributes  {System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo}    System.Reflection.RuntimeParameterInfo
> - Non-public members
>         BindingFlags    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Default  System.Reflection.BindingFlags
> - ReflectedTypeInternal   {System.RuntimeType}    System.RuntimeType
>         mhandle 0xffffffff91fc61a8  System.IntPtr
>         name    "Throw" string
> - reftype {System.RuntimeType}    System.RuntimeType
> - Static members
> - Non-public members
>         ErrorCode   -1  int
>         NativeErrorCode -1  int
> - Non-public members
>         ErrorCode   -1  int
>         Message "mono-io-layer-error (-1)"  string
>         SocketErrorCode System.Net.Sockets.SocketError.SocketError  System.Net.Sockets.SocketError
> - Non-public members
>         Message "mono-io-layer-error (-1)"  string
>         Source  "mscorlib"  string
>         StackTrace  "  at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync (System.String host, System.Int32 port, System.Threa…" string
> - TargetSite  {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo
> - Static members
> - Non-public members
>         _COMPlusExceptionCode   -532462766  int
> - s_EDILock   {object}    object
> - Non-public members
>         IsTransient System.NotImplementedException: The method or operation is not implemented. bool
>         RemoteStackTrace    (null)  string
>         _HResult    -2147467259 int
>         _className  "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException"  string
> - _data   {System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal} System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
>         _dynamicMethods (null)  object
>         _helpURL    (null)  string
> - _innerException {System.Net.Sockets.SocketException}    System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
>         _message    "mono-io-layer-error (-1)"  string
>         _remoteStackIndex   0   int
>         _remoteStackTraceString (null)  string
> - _safeSerializationManager   {System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager} System.Runtime.Serialization.SafeSerializationManager
>         _source "mscorlib"  string
> - _stackTrace {System.IntPtr[18]} System.IntPtr[]
>         _stackTraceString   (null)  string
> - captured_traces {System.Diagnostics.StackTrace[7]}  System.Diagnostics.StackTrace[]
>         caught_in_unmanaged 0   int
>         native_trace_ips    (null)  System.IntPtr[]

Comment: What are the details from the *`InnerException`* of the `HttpRequestException`?

Comment: @SushiHangover thanks for support. Detail exception i'm updated in post.